# Concatenation as a comma separated string - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of elements, two user input fields, and two buttons. User enters a value in the 1st input field and clicks on the button. The entered value should be appended to the existing list and should also reflect in the space provided below the input fields. All the added values should form a comma separated string.

Ex: car, bike, bus

How to concatenate a variable which is a user input value to form a comma separated line using jquery?

Html:

```
    <ol id="list">...</ol> 

    <input class="Add">
    <button id="btn1"> Add </button>
    Added item : <div class="Additem"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
var additem = $(".Add").val();
$("#list").append("<li>" + additem + "</li>");
$(".Additem").append("<div>" + additem + "</div>");
```

Line 4 in the above code appends the variable but in a different line.

Above operation shows a method of appending a user input value to list. What is the method to delete a user input value which is a part of list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    var additem = $(".Add").val();
    $("#list").append($("<li>").text(additem));
    $(".Additem").text(($(".Additem").text() + ', ' + additem).replace(/^, /, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="list"></ol> 
<input class="Add">
<button id="btn1"> Add </button><br>
Added item : <div class="Additem"></div>
```

#### Explanation

The addition of `', ' + additem` does not need explanation, but it will result in a string that starts with `,`, while the commas should only appear between items. This can be solved in many ways, but here I have applied a `replace` to remove any such comma from the start of the string:

```
.replace(/^, /, '')
```

The forward slashes (`/`) delimit a regular expression literal. The caret (`^`) requires the characters to be matched to be at the start of the string. The comma and space are taken literally. So if a comma-space sequence is found at the start of the string, it is replaced by `''` in the return value of the `replace` method.

#### Alternative

If you would start out with adding empty values to your list, the above solution would trim them from the string representation. So if in that case you want to see `, , , hello, world` (instead of `hello, world`) when the list shows 5 entries (first three empty), then you could use this code:

```js
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    var additem = $(".Add").val();
    $("#list").append($("<li>").text(additem));
    $(".Additem").text($("#list li").map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(', '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="list"></ol> 
<input class="Add">
<button id="btn1"> Add </button><br>
Added item : <div class="Additem"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Would like to know how can be a remove operation written? Just like adding to a list, if I want to remove an item from list. @trincot

Comment: That really is a different question. Feel free to post a new question, with an example, and code you have tried with. There will be lots of people going to help you with that, and ... you'll get some extra reputation if you write that question well. ;-)

Comment: @ananthreddy Use `.split()` to turn the string into an array. Remove the element from the array. Then use `.join()` to turn the array back into a comma-separated string.

Comment: @trincot Can you please elaborate on what is really happening in the part `replace(/^, /, '')`

Comment: Added explanation of the call to `replace`

Comment: @ananthreddy: i would make your proposal in some way safer.. what  if an entry contains one or more commas?

Comment: @trincot: substring(2) ? Blank entries appears in the UL but not in additem.

Comment: @deblocker, I added an alternative solution in case that is an issue for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".Additem").text($(".Additem").text() + ', ' + additem)
```

instead of your 4th line.